# Get cookie with specific path in a Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, path, controller

How do you retrieve a cookie value by name AND path?

By default, Rails grabs cookies `cookies[:name]` in the root path `/`

But how could you grab a cookie in a different path, say `/path_name`

Is there a way to do this in Rails?

Answer (score 1):

The cookies available to your controller are dependent on the path. Cookies are by default put in the root. But you can make a cookies[:name] entry that only shows up in a specific path by using the :path option like so:

```
cookies[:name] = {
  value: 'hello world',
  path: '/foo'
}
```

If you try accessing this cookie in a different path, it won't be there. The browser will only include this cookie in it's request IF the path matches the cookie path.

So, due to how cookies work, you can't get cookies from a path that is not your own. That would be really unsafe. If you are in "/foo", than you automatically have access to that cookie.